# How to make disk-based buffer just like memory?

Tags: c, linux, buffer

I have seen a similar question on this site, but there is no helpful answer.

> *Scenario*:
>   Following is the data transmission process ,
>   **embedded devices**-------->**buffer**-------->**AWS**(*Cloud Storage*)
>
> *Conditions*:
>   Owing to the limit of embedded device, there is not enough memory to store the data.
>
> *My idea*:
>   Using mmap() to allocate "memory" on disk, and manage the data relay on another lib, which is a opensource lib on github.
>
> *Problem*:
>   However, I discover it just now that the it will occupy memory in the real memory. This method seems cannot solve my condition.

What's your idea ? Buddy...

Comment: mmap() doesn't occupy real memory, it occupies virtual memory. Does your embedded device support mmap() and does it have an MMU(to provide memory abilities)

Comment: Yes, my device support mmap(). My testing program is: 1.open a file, lseek to 2GB. 2.Deliver the file description to mmap and it return me a pointer. 3.write 1 Byte data to the pointer-leading-buffer 0x7fffffff times(2GB data). 4.While the program is running, using 'pgrep' to get the pid of the test.out, and 'cat /proc/pid/status | grep VmRSS' to see the real memory. I find the VmRSS value grows as the swap-file

Comment: I'm glad we're buddies. :-D  Do you have or can you have external flash on your embedded device?

Comment: VmRSS is not "real memory usage".

Comment: Not? Then, how can I know a program occupies how much memory?

Answer (score 0):

All *mmmap(2)* does is to avoid an extra data copy operation between the user-space application's buffer and a kernel holding buffer.  The portion of the real file which is mapped becomes part of the application's virtual address space and occupies physical memory in the block cache, even if you are using an anonymous map (a map without a backing file, the fd arg is set to -1).

So, by moving the mmap(2) window you can gain direct access to the kernel's buffer cache holding the file data.  Use a 4K map window to correspond to the virtual memory map hardware feature and your file can be arbitrary size but only use a 4K map window into the file.

The good thing about mmap(2) is that you can open the file, create the mmap(2) window, and then close the file.  Now you can access the file data using loads/stores treating the mapped window as a data array object.